# MySQL recursive sleect

Tags: mysql, bash

I am also looking for recursive select in MySQl.

I have a table as

```
MariaDB [marin_bi_dim]> desc dim_sf_account;
+---------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id                              | varchar(512) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Name                            | varchar(512) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Customer__c                     | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ParentId                        | varchar(18)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Account_ID_18__c                | varchar(256) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Account_Tier_manual__c          | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Agency_of_Record__c             | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Type                            | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Subtype__c                      | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Territory__c                    | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Region__c                       | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| OwnerId                         | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Sales_Owner__c                  | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Customer_Engagement_Manager__c  | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Tier__c                         | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Account_Tier__c                 | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| BillingCity                     | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Last_MRR__c                     | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Average_Monthly_Revenue__c      | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Global_Ultimate_Account_Name__c | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pw_cc__BillingCountryLookup__c  | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| BillingCountry                  | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Account_Status__c               | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Social_Media_Consultant__c      | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Search_Customer__c              | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Social_Customer__c              | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Display_Customer__c             | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Social_Agency_of_Record__c      | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Network_Agency__c               | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
29 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Detail: Every employee has Id, parent_id is the boss's Id of Id. Parent_id can also be in Id and they may have parent_id or not. Id's that do not have parent_id could be the head of the tree. There is no one tree. Many trees could be formed.

Is it possible at all through MySQL select statement or do I need to create a bash script to execute this ?

Comment: Ouch! That's not a table, that's a log file. Is it possible for you to redefine the database structure to bring it closer to Third Normal Form?

Comment: @KenY-N how is that a log file?

Comment: @Drew it *is* a table, of course, but it's being used as just a dump for everything to it feels like just a log output.

Comment: What I don't like is the choice of datatypes. They are dreadful and will completely screw up performance.

Comment: We have a very large environment handling huge data with over 500 hosts each having 260G RAM and 2T /data.

Comment: Having a large environment doesn't justify having a non-normalized database. A full table scan will make your powerful server crawl to a halt.